# Teradata - How to get number acces by table and by month

Tags: sql, teradata, system-tables

I am tring to get an user number per table and per month.

I am trying to get read access (select and no update delete)
Do you know if it is possible to get this with view like dbc.tables ?

```
Database    |   Table   |   Date (YYYYMM)   |   Number of access | Number of distinct access
------------|-----------|-------------------|----------------------------------------------
PROD        | SALES     | 202004            | 500                | 300 
PROD        | SALES     | 202003            | 550                | 330
DEV         | SALES     | 202004            | 15                 | 10
```

P.S : English isn't my native langage => sorry

Comment: What constitutes "distinct" access? I suspect you may need to activate Query Logging (DBQL) "WITH OBJECTS" and possibly also "WITH USECOUNT" to derive this level of detail.

Comment: if users A use 6 time te tables TAB during the month, i want him to be count as 1 in the last column

Answer (score 0):

"Accesscount" column in dbc.tables will give you the number of times a particular object has been accessed.

Comment: That would just give you the total accesses, not by user or over time.  That would, I think (and as Fred suggested) require the query logging be enabled.